# Disabling num-lock toggle in C#?

Tags: c#, num-lock

I would like to maintain num-lock ON as long as my application is running, so that if the user un-toggles num-lock, it will immediately be toggled back on. What's the simplest way to achieve that in C#?

To clarify, while my application is running I "own" the user's machine, so in my specific case there will not be a need for the user to un-toggle num-lock (that does not mean I have focus at all times).

Thanks

Comment: By saying you "own" the machine, is that to say your application has focus 100% of the time?  As in, is doing the operation in KeyDown or ProcessCmdKey a valid option?

Comment: @Walt W: I may not have focus at all times, edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a few P/Invoke calls. Check out [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/statusbar/update_toggle_key_status.aspx)

Comment: That just checks it, but doesn't tell you WHEN it changes.  To detect the action of the user changing the num lock key requires a low level keyboard hook

Answer (score 1):

Enable `Form.KeyPreview` on your form, add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` (or you can use the native API directly to poll the state of the num lock key).

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    public const byte VK_NUMLOCK = 0x90;
    public const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
    public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    public static void SimulateKeyPress(byte keyCode)
    {
        keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
        keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool protectKeys; // To protect from inifite keypress chain reactions

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (protectKeys)
            return;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumLock && 
            !(new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Keyboard().NumLock))
        {
            protectKeys = true;
            NativeMethods.SimulateKeyPress(NativeMethods.VK_NUMLOCK);
            protectKeys = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a low level keyboard hook to do this.  Stephen Toub wrote a [tutorial on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) on setting this up.

Your keyboard hook can check the status of VK_NUMLOCK.  For a [VB example see here](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/hooks/setwindowshookex.htm).